# loginUserFromKeytab for UserGroupInformation accepts path for keytab file, works local but not when bundled as JAR

Tags: kubernetes, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, kerberos

I have all 4 files needed to read from/write to HDFS in my resources folder and method to create hdfs object is as below .

```
public  static FileSystem getHdfsOnPrem(String coreSiteXml, String hdfsSiteXml, String krb5confLoc, String keyTabLoc){
        // Setup the configuration object.
        try {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(coreSiteXml));
            config.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfsSiteXml));
            config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
            config.addResource(krb5confLoc);
            config.set("fs.hdfs.impl",org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
            config.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5confLoc);
            org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setConfiguration(config);
            UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("my_username", keyTabLoc);
            return org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(config);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It works when I run it in local and pass below as the paths

```
C:\Users\my_username\IdeaProjects\my_project_name\target\scala-2.12\classes\core-site.xml
C:\Users\my_username\IdeaProjects\my_project_name\target\scala-2.12\classes\hdfs-site.xml
C:\Users\my_username\IdeaProjects\my_project_name\target\scala-2.12\classes\krb5.conf
C:\Users\my_username\IdeaProjects\my_project_name\target\scala-2.12\classes\my_username.user.keytab
```

It runs fine when I run it in local but when I bundle it as JAR and run it in an env like kubernetes it throws below error (Since bundling as JAR I can read contents of resource files as stream but I need to pass in path for loginuserFromKeytab method)

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: for principal: my_username from keytab file:/opt/spark-3.0.0/jars/foo-project-name!/my_username.user.keytab javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

Any suggestions/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You mean you store your security credentials inside your code (on Git) and inside your binaries? Yuck...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter They are not on git, I am testing everything locally atm. Where are these files usually stored if my compute is on cloud (Azure kubernetes service) and trying to connect to bunch of hadoop nodes to read/write to?

Comment: Can you complete a kinit with the user that will run the application using 'my_username' & the keytab file and add that output to this question?  This will help to show you have permissions to access the keytab.

Comment: @MattAndruff Yes this keytab file works, I can do kinit etc. It works on connecting to hdfs from my local but not sure how to give path once I made my code into JAR since the relative path isn't working and I am not sure what absolute path would be inside JAR or where should I even place my keytab file so java code can read it?

Comment: I respectfully suggest that you do not bundle it.  You set it according to a known enviroment variable (with a reasonable default set as a backup.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Jaas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html#:%7E:text=JAAS%20can%20be%20used%20for,bean%2C%20or%20a%20servlet%3B%20and) config file instead of writing this code.  This helps to remove the security plumbing from your code and externalizes it.  "Unable to obtain password " would occur if the user that is running your app doesn't have permission to access the file.